# Moment.js output cant read time 00.00, clue* : if tue start at 00.00 it will be changes by wed at 00.00

Tags: javascript, laravel, mobile, content-management-system

## ***[First code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPK87.png)***

`Here, i attach the code by photo  and i want the output like this : tue, (date) 00.00 a.m and it will changes tue to wed 00.00 a.m.`

**`help me for this.  i used moment.js for this code. but system read the output like : Tue 24/07/23 23.00 (it changed to wed before 00.00`**